# Is there a way to inject observe: 'response' from HttpInterceptor in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

My app receives a custom header in response from web api using the following **this._http.get("SomeUrl", {observe:"response"});**
I'm able to set the headers and params in HttpInterceptor to make all api calls and receive the response with custom header. 
My question is if there is a way to set {observe:"response"} in HttpInterceptor for all the api calls just like we can set headers and parameters globally?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{observe:"response"}); has to be always along with the http method call as an argument. Custom response header then could be read in HttpInterceptor.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for this. Did you come across any documentation stating this. ?