# Angular Http full response using HttpClient with HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I use many http request in Angular 4.

Now, I'll upgrade to Angular 6 with full response with `HttpClient`.

i'll try to `{observe: 'response'}` params in `HttpInterceptor`

my code like below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setParams: { observe: 'response' },
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

but it is not working

sure it work fine very well

```
return this.httpClient.get(url, { observe: 'response' });
```

i already find my question that very similar ( link : [Is there a way to inject observe: 'response' from HttpInterceptor in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448703/is-there-a-way-to-inject-observe-response-from-httpinterceptor-in-angular-6) )

Sadly, he seems to have found the answer alone. I ask you if it is really impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you're trying to do; I have previously also failed to observe the response, but I was after the headers and successfully used this:

Typescript

```
const httpOptions = {
        observe:'response',
    };
this.httpClient.post(url, data, httpOptions) // this errors on typeerror (so comment out the 'observe')
.subscribe(resp => {
  console.log('resp',(resp as any).headers.get('Location')) // we still actually have access to it
})
```

Comment: So Sad..... is that cant possible any way to receive Full response with HttpInterceptor.? T_T.... Why HttpInterceptor didnt support { observe: 'response' } ??